# how to iterate complex object from the api response

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, javascript-objects

This is an api response and I want to iterate all the `appId` and `userInfo` from the response. How can i iterate over this response ?

```
{
    "status_code": "SUCCESS",
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "message": "Success",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "6034acaaf751f1c89721a76b",
            "status": "active",
            "name": "testname",
            "collectionStatus": "completed",
            "createdDate": 1614064810201,
            "subscriberStats": [],
            "platforms": [
                {
                    "_id": "6034acaa47a83e45b3f5fc4a",
                    "status": "active",
                    "traffic": 0,
                    "parentStatus": "active",
                    "platformType": "website",
                    "appId": "xxx",
                    "optinShowInterval": 0,
                    "optInFrequencyType": "page_refresh",
                    "webType": "wordpress",
                    "optInFrequency": 0,
                    "userId": "xxx",
                    "createdDate": 1614064810563
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "600ae310255964c2e21a580f",
            "status": "active",
            "name": "trial",
            "collectionStatus": "completed",
            "createdDate": 1611326224761,
            "subscriberStats": [],
            "platforms": [
                {
                    "_id": "600ae31163d6d321f4693d1d",
                    "status": "active",
                    "traffic": 0,
                    "parentStatus": "active",
                    "platformType": "website",
                    "webType": "wordpress",
                    "appId": "xxx",
                    "optinShowInterval": 0,
                    "optInFrequencyType": "page_refresh",
                    "optInFrequency": 0,
                    "userId": "xxx",
                    "createdDate": 1611326225013
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

the resulting output should be an array of objects, for eg:

```
[
   {appId: "", userInfo: ""},
   {appId: "", userInfo: ""}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

appId and usetId is nested deep inside object inside platforms array
you can access them by using following code

```js
const res = {
  status_code: "SUCCESS",
  status: "SUCCESS",
  message: "Success",
  data: [
    {
      _id: "6034acaaf751f1c89721a76b",
      status: "active",
      name: "testname",
      collectionStatus: "completed",
      createdDate: 1614064810201,
      subscriberStats: [],
      platforms: [
        {
          _id: "6034acaa47a83e45b3f5fc4a",
          status: "active",
          traffic: 0,
          parentStatus: "active",
          platformType: "website",
          appId: "xxx",
          optinShowInterval: 0,
          optInFrequencyType: "page_refresh",
          webType: "wordpress",
          optInFrequency: 0,
          userId: "xxx",
          createdDate: 1614064810563,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      _id: "600ae310255964c2e21a580f",
      status: "active",
      name: "trial",
      collectionStatus: "completed",
      createdDate: 1611326224761,
      subscriberStats: [],
      platforms: [
        {
          _id: "600ae31163d6d321f4693d1d",
          status: "active",
          traffic: 0,
          parentStatus: "active",
          platformType: "website",
          webType: "wordpress",
          appId: "xxx",
          optinShowInterval: 0,
          optInFrequencyType: "page_refresh",
          optInFrequency: 0,
          userId: "xxx",
          createdDate: 1611326225013,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

const output = res.data.map((obj) => {
  return { appId: obj.platforms[0].appId, userId: obj.platforms[0].userId };
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some loops:

```
const result = [];
for (const a in response) {
  for (const b of response[a]) {
    result.push({
      appId: b._id,
      userInfo: b.parentStatus // or some other properties
    })
  }
}

console.log(result)
```